# Q: How to make it so player can jump to wherever I tap, but not keep moving up when touch is held?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im creating a game like Doodle jump, and I want it to be so that my hero does jump to wherever I tap, but when I hold that touch on the screen, it just keeps moving up until it is off screen, which isn't what I'm aiming for. I just want it to be so that no matter how much I tap and hold, my hero does not keep moving up.

Here is my code for my touches functions:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    player.animatePlayer()
    let touch = touches.first as? UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    lastTouch = touchLocation
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = snowCategory
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory
        player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true



    }




   override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    lastTouch = nil



}



  override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    lastTouch = nil
    }
      override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        var xForce: CGFloat = 0.0
        var yForce: CGFloat = 0.0
        let xTouchOffset = (touch.x - player.position.x)
        let yTouchOffset = (touch.y - player.position.y)

        if xTouchOffset > 0.0 {
            xForce = xPlayerForce
        } else if xTouchOffset < 0.0 {
            xForce = -xPlayerForce
        } // else we do nothing

        if yTouchOffset > 0.0 {
            yForce = yPlayerForce
        } else if xTouchOffset > 0.0 {
            yForce = -yPlayerForce
        }
        // here you can choose whether you want it to push
        // the player node down, using similar code from the
        // above if statement

        let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: xForce, dy: yForce)
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your object movement is activated when you lift your finger. Instead of doing this, I would say put your code in touches began, or at least have some way of stopping the object when it gets where you want. Right now you have it in an update method that continues to run after you lift your finger, so that's why it keeps going.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean?